# how to prepare the comma separated strings with guid in this scenario?

Tags: c#

Hi I am having Generic List ob object  School. having schoolId as GUID and school name as String.

say list of object school having School Id and School name properties as :

```
                  School Id              Name
'C33BB532-895B-4DB7-BA59-1BC5B580902B'=> "S1"
'C33BB532-895B-4DB7-BA59-1BC5B580902B'=> "S2"
'C33BB532-895B-4DB7-BA59-1BC5B580902B'=> "S3"
'3454D83D-68CA-4A9C-9185-1E49AE1C16DC'=> "S4"
'3454D83D-68CA-4A9C-9185-1E49AE1C16DC'=> "S5"
'3454D83D-68CA-4A9C-9185-1E49AE1C16DC'=> "S6"
```

I need output like this in Select Item List to populate in dropdown:

```
     ID                                      Value
'C33BB532-895B-4DB7-BA59-1BC5B580902B' =>  "S1,S2,S3" 
'3454D83D-68CA-4A9C-9185-1E49AE1C16DC'=>   "S4,S5,S6"
```

I am using c# with MVC. How can i get this?

Comment: List of what? Where? Show us how you are creating this list.

Comment: `GroupBy` `Id`, but it's kinda not clear what you actually want.

Comment: its very clear by data. It is List of School object that having the properties SchoolId and SchoolName. s1,s2,s3...are the names.

Comment: Please check the answer and give your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `GroupBy`. Assume that your pairs are stored in a class like this:

```
class Pair {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Val {get;set;}
}
```

You can produce the desired result as follows:

```
foreach (var g in data.GroupBy(p=>Id)) {
    Console.WriteLine(                  // Change this to the desired destination
        "{0} => {1}"
    ,   g.Key                                     // Produces GUID
    ,   string.Join(",", g => g.Select(p=>p.Val)) // Makes a comma-separated list
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks This worked for me. But a little change need in code._groupItems.Add(_schools.FirstOrDefault().schoolGroupId, string.Join(",", _school.Select(s => s.schoolName)));

Answer (score 0):

Try group by in LINQ like

```
var res = from g in yourlist.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
          select new { SchoolId = g.Key, SchoolName = string.Join(",", g.Select(gg => gg.name).ToArray()) };
```